# Help at dismissing a time dilation "paradox"

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

If Observer A moves at speed $v$ respect to observer B, then there is a time dilation given by

$$t_B=t_A\gamma$$

as is known from special relativity. Here, $t_A$ is the time interval measured by A and $t_B$ is the time interval measured by B. However, a friend of mine asked me about the inverse case, what if we take the frame of reference in which A is stationary and B is moving?
in that case, 
$$t_A=t_B\gamma$$

In this case, A's time should be dilated with respect to B's, since B is moving away, so we get conflicting results. I know that this case is somehow erroneous, but I am now sure how to justify it. I think that it has something to do with the fact that in the first equation, $t_A $ is the proper time, and that is the one that is dilated, but I have been unsuccesful at developing a convincing enough argument. How can I solve this "paradox"?

Comment: I wrote an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/521845/157014) a while back about essentially the same misconception, but dealing with length contraction instead of time dilation, you should be able to figure out the answer using the arguments there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can time dilation be symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383248/)

Comment: Why is paradox in air-quotes? This is absolutely a paradox.